# Contact form not sending form values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using an upgrade version of [stepsForm.js](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/04/01/minimal-form-interface/) from codrops. Anyway the contact form sends the email but none of the values from the input i.e `$_POST['email']`. The PHP...

```html
<?php

$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_residence = $_POST['residence'];
$field_profession = $_POST['profession'];
$field_club = $_POST['fave_club'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];


$mail_to = 'idwapro2@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from vidz.dundaah visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'E-mail: '."\n".$field_email."\n\n";
$body_message .= 'Name: '."\n".$field_name."\n\n";
$body_message .= 'Residence: '."\n".$field_residence."\n\n";
$body_message .= 'Profession: '."\n".$field_profession."\n\n";
$body_message .= 'Fave_club: '."\n".$field_club."\n\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '."\n".$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_name."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  window.location = '../contact.html';
 </script>
<?php

?>
```

The HTML form... and js file [stepsForm.js](http://deez.site90.com/contact/js/contactForm.js) and css file [stepsForm.css](http://deez.site90.com/contact/css/contactForm.css)

```html
<section class="cool_form">
  <form action="css/contactForm.php" id="theForm" class="simform" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="simform-inner">
      <ol class="questions">
        <li>
          <span><label for="q1">What's your email?</label></span>
          <input id="q1" name="email" type="email" spellcheck="false" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <span><label for="q2">What's your name?</label></span>
          <input id="q2" name="name" type="text" spellcheck="false" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <span><label for="q3">Where do you live?</label></span>
          <input id="q3" name="residence" type="text" spellcheck="false" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <span><label for="q4">What do you do?</label></span>
          <input id="q4" name="profession" type="text" spellcheck="false" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <span><label for="q5">Favourite club?</label></span>
          <input id="q5" name="fave_club" type="text" spellcheck="false" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <span><label for="q6">Tell us something...</label></span>
          <input id="q6" name="message" type="text" spellcheck="false" />
        </li>
      </ol>
      <button class="submit" type="submit">Send answers</button>
      <div class="controls">
        <button class="previous"></button>
        <button class="next"></button>
        <div class="progress"></div>
        <span class="number">
        <span class="number-current"></span>
        <span class="number-total"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="error-message"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="final-message"></span>
  </form>
</section>
```

basically getting "Email: blank space", "Name: blank.." etc. thank you!

Comment: default method of form is $_GET.And you are trying to get form value using post method. Try using method="post" in form tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `method="post"` to your HTML `<form>` tag. Forms will default to `$_GET` unless you specify to use a different HTTP request method. If you look at your address bar after submitting your existing form, you'll probably see all the submitted parameters in the URL.

Here's how your `<form>` tag should look:

```
<form action="css/contactForm.php" id="theForm" class="simform" autocomplete="off" method="post">
```

Comment: I would also do change you php script to check that data has actually been posted like as such `if (!empty($_POST))` and also loop through your required fields to see if they exists before attempting to send the email :) good luck

Comment: wow thanks can't believe i made such an omission. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @codenathan i already have javascript making sure the fields are filled and validated

Comment: so what happens if i disable javascript on my browser and submit your form ? your php script fails you can even do a simple one like this http://www.w3schools.in/php/form-validation/

Answer (score 2):

Use `method` attribute of form with value `post` like

```
<form method="post" ......
```